# PHP simplexml children to lowercase

Tags: php, simplexml, lowercase

I've got this as XML:

```
...
<product>
<id>1</id>
<defaultImage>test.jpg</defaultImage>
</product>
...
```

I've got this as php:

```
$testcase = 'defaultimage';
$xml = simplexml_load_file('./temp/'.$i.'.xml');
foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {
    $child->$testcase;
}
```

Now the problem is this, I'm forced to have `$testcase` in a lowercase form (defaultimage) BUT in the XML file the name of the child is: `defaultImage` (note the uppercase I)

Question: How can I handle all the children as lowercases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `->getName()` method to find out the name of a node while looping through an inner `->children()` array.

For clarity, I've used a more explicit loop over all `product` nodes for the outer loop

```
$testcase = 'defaultimage';
$xml = simplexml_load_file('./temp/'.$i.'.xml');
foreach ( $xml->product as $product )
{
   foreach ( $product->children as $child )
   {
      if ( strtolower($child->getName()) == $testcase )
      {
         // Do whatever it is you need to do with the <defaultImage> node
      }
   }
}
```